# Can we use Jquery in windows application?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, c#-4.0

I want to use some of the features of jquery like item drag and drop..So can we use jquery in windows application(c#)?

Answer (score 6):

You could include a [`WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) in your WinForms or WPF application and use jQuery from within the web browser.

In addition there is [Chromium Embedded](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) which you can also use from .NET (See the "[External Projects](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/#External_Projects)" section). This gives you the core web browser engine of the Google Chrome web browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are few project started to push Nodejs on desktop application. But still in very amateur phase you have to wait for a while... But if you are planning for Windows 8 application, it is possible in very limited manner. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use that but you can make use of [WPF control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) to achieving that in your application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - hi you can check this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation

Comment: I know what WPF is. I don't know what it had to do with jquery

Comment: @JohnSaunders- its nothing has to do with jquery but the the jquery you can achieve it with WPF in windows application because jquery is made up for web devlopment not for windows devlopment

Comment: @JohnSaunders - the question is about using juqery in windows application...not about jQuery..and answer is no its not possible to use jquery in windows application alrenativly same thing can achieve using WPF windows application...

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use Jint to run javascript but for jquery, it needs DOM. so unless you don't want UI you cannot do it.

> cscript, wscript and the Windows Scripting Host objects allow you to do things that you can't do from within a browser, but these are very much limited to scripting tasks, and won't allow you to create a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery run in the browser like IE, Chrom etc. you can't use jquery in windows application.